# Why is my scaled img disappearing on y-axis with `overflow-x: scroll` setting?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to achieve a behaviour similar to Netflix's carousels.

I have a line of movies with `overflow-x: scroll` and a scale effect on the images on hover.

However, for some reason, the `overflow-x: scroll` alone seems to be sort of applying `overflow-y: hidden` and I don't understand why...

See the following fiddle for examples on how it's behaving and how I want it to behave:
https://jsfiddle.net/b3exagky/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I looked up info in the W3C spec for this and it says:

> The computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’ are the same as their specified values, except that some combinations with ‘visible’ are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’. The computed value of ‘overflow’ is equal to the computed value of ‘overflow-x’ if ‘overflow-y’ is the same; otherwise it is the pair of computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’.

So basically when you set either `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` to something other than `visible`, the other one is interpreted as `auto` automatically. To fix your problem, you should make the container a bigger height to accommodate for the added height when scaled.

Comment: Thanks for looking it up. It kind of makes sense, however increasing the height of the container isn't a viable solution in this case because the carousels will be too far apart. I'll see if I can find another solution ;)